# Why open a stream with fopen and perform I/O using read/write (not fread/fwrite)

Tags: c++, g++, libstdc++

Whilst looking at the implementation of `basic_filebuf` in `libstd++` (GNU CC 4.9.2), I came across the `__basic_file` class and I can't fathom the design rationale. Specifically:

1. `__basic_file::open` is implemented using C stdio `fopen`
2. `__basic_file::sync` is implemented using C stdio `fflush`
3. All other methods are implemented using system calls (e.g. `read`, `write`, `lseek`)

I can see why I/O is performed using system calls (`filebuf` / `streambuf` implement their own buffering) but *why bother open the file with C stdio in the first place*?

And why flush the stdio buffer in `sync` (doesn't that potentially introduce some weird edge cases)? For instance, if for some reason `fwrite` was called by client code in addition to performing C++ stream writes, then write order might not be respected (i.e. a `filebuf` write occurs, `fwrite` occurs but doesn't fill the stdio buffer and actually output anything, `filebuf` writes again and `sync` is called explicitly or implicitly... then the `fwrite` data would be written last - I realise it's a contrived example, but theoretically possible).

Comment: Please add any edge cases that you can think of to your question. That will improve the quality of the question.

Comment: @R Sahu: I've added a somewhat contrived example, although the 'edge cases' weren't the main point of the question.

Comment: That's probably one reason why are discouraged to mix stdio and C++ streams.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard function, std::base_io::sync_with_stdio, which can be used to turn off the default and potentially costly syncing of raw C io and the buffered C++ stuff. I have no conclusive proof right here and now, but I'd hazard a guess this implies (by inverse logic) that your edge cases are covered.

Comment: Nice idea - got me doing a fair amount of code reading. Unfortunately, it is not the case: `sync_with_stdio` switches between `stdio_sync_filebuf` and `stdio_filebuf` for the standard C++ streams (e.g. `cout`, etc...). Now the former is implemented using a `FILE` member and the expected `fread`/`fwrite` calls. The latter is a refinement of `basic_filebuf`. So doesn't explain why `__basic_file` uses `fopen`/`fflush` and `read`/`write` (rather than `open` and NOP `sync`).

Comment: @isedev You might try asking [@Jonathan Wakely](http://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely) directly, he's bound to know the details.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why `sync` implements `fflush` but I have understood why a file is opened with `fopen`:

- All the file access methods, even though implemented using system calls such as `read`, `write` and `lseek`, call an `fd` method to obtain the file descriptor;
- The `fd` method uses `fileno` on the class' stdio `FILE` member to obtain the file descriptor.

Now `fileno` will return `-1` (an invalid file descriptor) if the `FILE` structure does not corresponds to a valid stream. This means that there is no need to implement any logic in the file access methods to check whether the file is actually open.

This avoids the nasty situation where a `__basic_file` is created then closed (not destroyed), another file is opened re-using the same file descriptor (which is possible since `open` uses the smallest available file descriptor) and then I/O is attempted against the closed `__basic_file` (which, without the above logic, would actually lead to I/O against the unrelated file).